# Segfault only when printing

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I have a loop that looks something like this

```
while(condition){
  read_some_data(source, buf, BUFSIZE);
  printf(buf);
  memset(buf, 0, BUFSIZE+1);
  //do stuff to affect condition that does not touch buf
}
```

`buf` is an char array of size `BUFSIZE+1`.  The strange thing is that if I comment out the `printf`, the program executes perfectly with no segmentation fault.  It is only when I try to print out `buf` that I get the problem.  Also, the seg fault does not necessarily happen on the first iteration of the loop.  It usually takes 6 or 7 iterations.

Also, there is no dynamic memory allocation in this program.

Comment: What happens if you use `printf()` correctly? i.e. `printf("%s", buf);`

Comment: @DanFego I'm so embarrassed. That was my problem.

Comment: no need to be embarrassed as long as you've learned something! That is, how to use `printf()` and perhaps to use `-Wall` and to pay attention to compiler warnings. :)

Comment: Has anything changed last 20 years or so? I thought that `printf("abc");`would have the same effect as `printf("%s","abc");` I'm afraid this is just temporarily hiding a problem with the heap

Comment: @stacker: think about what happens if `buf` contains any `%` characters

Comment: @PaulR Good point, upvoted the answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Make sure that `buf` has a null (zero-valued) byte somewhere within the allocated range. That null byte is how `printf` can tell that it's reached the end of a string; without it, it will keep reading past where it can safely do so.
- Make sure that `buf` doesn't contain anything like `%d` that `printf` might take to indicate additional arguments. Better yet — just use `printf("%s", buf)`, which completely eliminates any such risk.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the format specifier argument to printf

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `buf` is `\0` terminated string.
Only then `printf()` could print the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the string as a print parameter: `printf("%s", buf);`.

Hope this helps!

N.S.

Answer (score 0):

Is it null-terminated?  And why are you calling printf(buf) rather than puts(buf) if all you want to do is to write out the buf to stdout?